# terminal error showing could not find or load main class

Tags: java, visual-studio, class, terminal, compiler-errors

In visual studio code. my code is not running properly. There is no syntax error or any error but it is not running. please tell me the solution. it will really appreciated.[image] java path is also ok.

i had tried all possible outcomes but terminal is only showing error could not load main class, caused by java.lang.classnotfoundexception: javabasics.java[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

In java, the name of the class must be consistent with the file name

Try to modify the file name or class name

Maybe it's not because of Top-level

[image]

Comment: only the case for public top-level class, posted images apparently show a non-public class

Comment: Not because of top-level

Comment: In my test, it ran normally without public

Comment: What? I asked what you meant by "*Not because of top-level*", now you come with "*ran normally without public*"??? As I wrote, "*the name of the class must be consistent with the file name*" (you claimed in the answer) is only valid for a public top-level class - that means, that if the class is "*without public*" it does not need to be such a named file, so obviously it "*ran normally*"